# How could I create a JSON array in a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to create a javascript json array. At the and I would Like to have something like this  :

```
var requestData= {"uris":["SampleName1", "SampleName2", "SampleName3"],"limit":100 };
```

The names are stored in another variable called `result.results.bindings` I think my for loop should be like this :

```
for(binding in result.results.bindings){
  // binding holds SampleName1,sampleName2.. etc         

}
```

So how could I create the array that I mentioned above?

Comment: Surely `result.results.bindings` is already an array / object?

Comment: `var a = []; for(var b in result.results.bindings) a.push(result.results.bindings[b]); var json = {uris:a,limit:100}`

Comment: @BenM yes but its type is not what I want.

Comment: Then you should post the value of `bindings` here. It's impossible to suggest how to create an array without knowing what is inside.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var data = [];
for(binding in result.results.bindings)
    data.push(binding);
var returnObject = {uris: data, limit: 100};
```

I do not know the structure of your data in result.results.bindings, but with the for loop you are looping over the keys of the object / array.

If you want to loop over the values and the data-source is an array you can use this:

```
var data = [];
result.results.bindings.forEach(function(value) {
    data.push(value);
});
var returnObject = {uris: data, limit: 100};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestData = {};
var uris = [];

for (binding in result.results.bindings){
   uris.push(binding);
}
requestData.uris = uris;
```

Edited as suggestion from @BenM:

```
var requestData = {};

requestData.uris = result.results.bindings;
```

Comment: Why not just assign `result.results.bindings` to `requestData.uris`?

Answer (score 0):

I think for-in loop is not a good practice with array, It's good with object

```
for(var i = 0, uris = []; i < result.results.bindings.length; i++)
   uris.push(result.results.bindings[i]);

var returnObject = {"uris": uris, "limit": 100};

console.log(returnObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 var data = [];
result.results.bindings.forEach(function(value) {
    eval('data.' + value + ' = ' + value);
});

// then access your variables like
alert(data.SampleName1);
```

Comment: DV for recommending `eval()`.